# Eclipse missing the Android Activity from its new file wizard

Tags: android, eclipse

As the title says, File > New > Other... Expanded Android. There is no Android Activity I can only see
Android Icon Set, Android Project, Android Sample Project, Android Test Project, Android XML File, Android XML Layout File, Android XML Values File

Not sure why it is missing.

Comment: have u try re-install the eclipse? perhaps during installation something might disturb the process.

Comment: oh, partially right. I reinstalled the android sdk. I think this software was the culprit, may have forgot to install the first time.
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/